# How can I federate custom scalar type cross subgraph via Apollo federation?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

I have below graphql schema defined in a apollo server works as a subgraph behind Apollo federation router.

```
extend schema @link(url: "https://specs.apollo.dev/federation/v2.0", import: ["@key", "@shareable"])

  scalar DateTime @shareable

  type _Service {
    sdl: String
  }  

  # This "Book" type defines the queryable fields for every book in our data source.
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
    date: DateTime
  }
```

It has a custom scalar type `DateTime`. I marked it as `@sharable` in order to make this type visible in other subgraph. But when I try to launch this Apollo server I got below error:

```
GraphQLError: Directive "@shareable" may not be used on SCALAR.
```

It says `@shareable` is not shareable. How can I make a custom type available in other sub-graphs?